# How do I use categorical_hinge in Keras?

Tags: keras, keras-2, loss-function, activation-function

Maybe a very dumb question but I can't find an example how to use categorical_hinge in Keras. I do classification and my target is `shape(,1)` with values [-1,0,1] so I have 3 categories. Using the functional API I have set up my output layer like this:

> output = Dense(1, name='output', activation='tanh',
>   kernel_initializer='lecun_normal')(output1)

Then I apply:

> model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss={'output': 'categorical_hinge'}, 
>   metrics=['accuracy'])

The result is that the model is converging but accuracy goes towards to 0. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `[-1, 0, 1]` is a valid target range for your tanh activation function, experience tells that Keras models don't work well with classification in a binary output. Consider using three one-hot vectors with a softmax classifier instead. If I interpret [this bug report](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2830) correctly, categorical hinge is built to work with one-hot vectors anyway.

So: Convert your labels to one-hots and change your output to something along the lines of:

```
output = Dense(3, name='output', activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='lecun_normal')(output1)
```

Comment: Answer is correct with the only mistake that [-1, 0, 1] is not a binary output. All the rest is correct.

Comment: Do you need to add activation='softmax' in Keras? Mathematically, hinge loss applies on distance, which does not have to be between (0 and 1). While crossentropy loss applies on probability, so it requires softamx before using the loss function.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss="categorical_hinge", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Would you like to augment your code-only answer with some explanation?

Comment: The question was why the accuracy is reducing instead of growing. The code runs without error.